# Proving that an expression is not a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $y = 3x^2 + 11$. Is it possible to prove that $y$ is never a perfect square for any integer value of $x$? I tried to think along the lines of induction, but such a method would depend on showing that the term does not have the properties of a perfect square, and these properties are very ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A square is equal to $0$ or $1$ mod $3$ but not equal to $2$ mod $3$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh cool, thanks. I didn't know anything about modular arithmetic before, but I googled "mod math" and I found a simple wikipedia page explaining it, so now I understand your answer. Can you point me to a proof for this relationship?

Comment: Any number $x$ is equal to $0,1$ or $2$ mod $3$ and then $x^2$ is equal to $0^2=0,1^2=1$ or $2^2=4=1$ mod $3$ so there is no number $x$ such that $x^2=2$ mod $3$.

Comment: And here $x$ is an integer? Or any rational number?

Comment: @TheOddbodNumber It does not have to be integer to solve, but integer solutions are easiest to find.

Answer (score 1):

$$3x^2+11\equiv2\equiv-1\pmod3$$

But for any integer $a,a^2\equiv0,1\pmod3$

Answer (score 1):

To add on to what everyone else has pointed out, see that we have:

$$1=1^2$$

$$1+3=2^2$$

$$1+3+5+\dots(2n-1)=n^2$$

This is easily proved using summation formulas.

We want to show that $n^2\equiv0,1\pmod3$

$$1\equiv1\pmod3$$

$$1+3\equiv1\pmod3$$

$$1+3+5\equiv0\pmod3$$

$$1+3+5+7\equiv1+3+5+(7-6)\equiv(1+3+5)+1\equiv0+1\pmod3$$

We see that we can just subtract a multiple of $3$ from every group of $3$ numbers, making $n^2\equiv0,1\pmod3$ because this result will repeat itself every three terms.

It is also fairly obvious that $3n\equiv0\pmod3$, which simply means that when we divide $3n$ by $3$, the result will have remainder $0$.

So, we have $$3x^2\equiv0\pmod3$$

$$3x^2+11\equiv11\equiv2\pmod3$$

And since this result is not $0,1$, then it is not a perfect square.